# Give $x,y,z: \begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=5\\x-y+z=3\end{cases}$. Find Min, Max of $P=\frac{x+y-2}{z+2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Give $x,y,z: \begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=5\\x-y+z=3\end{cases}$

Find Min, Max of $P=\frac{x+y-2}{z+2}$

Please help me ?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried? Do you know anything about Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: I have no idea for this, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit 1:

It is easy to go directly:

$x^2+(x+z)^2+z^2=5 \implies x= \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{1+6z-3z^2}-z+3}{2},y=\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{1+6x-3x^2}+z-3}{2},1-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\le z\le 1+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

$P= \dfrac{\pm2\sqrt{1+6z-3z^2}-2}{z+2}$

edit2:

$P=-\dfrac{2(1+\sqrt{1+6z-3z^2})}{z+2},P'=-\dfrac{2(\sqrt{-3z^2+6z+1}+9z-5) }{\sqrt{-3z^2+6z+1}(z^2+4z+4)}=0,z_1=\dfrac{4-\sqrt{2}}{7},P_{min}=P(z_1)$,

$P=\dfrac{2(\sqrt{1+6z-3z^2}-1)}{z+2},P'=\dfrac{2(\sqrt{-3z^2+6z+1}-9z+5) }{\sqrt{-3z^2+6z+1}(z^2+4z+4)}=0,z_2=\dfrac{4+\sqrt{2}}{7},P_{max}=P(z_2)$

Comment: Could you help me solve this ?

Comment: @K.D.H.D. I update the solution which is more easy.